Alternate solution to EGMO 2020 Problem 1
I was going through problem 1 in the EGMO 2020, which asks:

The positive integers $a_0,a_1,a_2,…,a_{3030}$ satisfy $$2a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+4a_{n}\text{ for }n=0,1,2,…,3028$$ Prove that at least one of the numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,…,a_{3030}$ is divisible by $2^{2020}$


While the pdf linked above does provide a solution, I have come up with an alternate proof:
Let $v_n$ be the greatest integer so that $2^{v_n}$ divides $a_n$
From $2a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+4a_{n}$, we get that $$v_{n+2}+1=\min{(v_{n+1},v_{n}+2)}\tag{i}$$
Lemma 1: $v_{n}-v_{n+1}=1\implies v_{n+1}-v_{n+2}=1$

Proof: $v_{n+2}=\min{(v_{n+1},v_{n}+2)}-1=\min{(v_{n+1},v_{n+1}+3)}-1=v_{n+1}-1$

Lemma 2: $v_2-v_3=1$

Proof:
Case 1 ($v_0<v_1-2$):
In this case, using $\text{(i)}$, we get $v_2=v_0+1$ and then, $v_3=v_0$. Thus $v_2-v_3=1$.
Case 2 ($v_0\geq v_1-2$):
In this case, using $\text{(i)}$, we get $v_2=v_1-1$ and then, $v_3=v_1-2$. Thus $v_2-v_3=1$.

Now, using Lemma 1 and Lemma 2: $v_2,v_3,…,v_{3030}$ form an arithmetic progression with common difference of $-1$
Also, none of $v_2,v_3,…,v_{3030}$ can be negative (as $a_2,a_3,…,a_{3030}$ are all positive integers), thus $v_2\geq3028$, and so $a_2$ is a term which is divisible by $2^{2020}$

I would be very grateful if someone could comment on the accuracy of this proof, and point out any possible errors. I am just beginning to try my hand at math competitions and it would be very useful to know if my method is correct.

Edit:
I have tried to find errors in my proof, but have yet found none. I have never before solved any question using the p-adic valuation of a number (here $v_n$ is the $2$-adic valuation of $a_n$). Thus, I am doubtful if $\text{(i)}$ is a valid conclusion that can be drawn directly from the given statement, or if I need to prove it independently.
Apart from that, I would be happy to hear about any improvements/errors found in my proof.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site should not be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque Oh, ok. I will try to edit accordingly. Sorry

@BillDubuque Done. Is it OK now?

Please say precisely which step of your proof of $(1)$ that you doubt, and why (mathematically) it is in doubt.

One point to note is that $v_{n+2}+1\ge \min{(v_{n+1},v_{n}+2)}\tag{i}$, equality doesn't necessarily hold

@DS Ah missed that. The ‘$>$’ case can happen when $v_{n+1}=v_n+2$, right? Otherwise, equality holds?

Yes, that's right
